# I want output of sql Query and i already done some query part but it fails

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The query which i have written

```
   SELECT Date_current,
          COUNT(*) as'Total' 
     FROM Call_Register 
    WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd,'02/1/2014',Date_current)  >=0) 
      AND (DATEDIFF(dd,'02/12/2014',Date_current) <=0) 
 GROUP BY Date_current
   HAVING COUNT(*)>=(convert(int,'02/12/2014')) \
 ORDER BY Date_current
```

But this query gives me error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '02/12/2014' to data type int.
```

```
   Date              Total
----------          -------
Feb  3 2014 2:58PM    10
Feb  4 2014 2:59PM    10
```

Please Help me

getting Output like

Date                      Total
----------                   -------
Feb  3 2014  2:58PM         1
Feb  3 2014  2:59PM         1
Feb  3 2014  3:00PM         1
Feb  3 2014  3:08PM         1
Feb  3 2014  3:20PM         1
Feb  3 2014  4:05PM         1
Feb  3 2014  4:17PM         1
Feb  3 2014  4:19PM         1
Feb  3 2014  4:21PM         1
Feb  3 2014  4:24PM         1
Feb  4 2014  1:11PM         1
Feb  4 2014  2:35PM         1 
Feb  4 2014  2:37PM         1
Feb  4 2014  5:19PM         1

Comment: Convert to epoch time and run the query.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: What is `convert(int,'02/12/2014')` meant to do?

Comment: i had mention the output

Comment: You should not edit your question to show the solution. That defies the Q&A character of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should either use the culture invariant date format `yyyyMMdd`, or explicitly set the date format using `SET DATEFORMAT DMY`, or prepare to get inconsistent results.

Secondly, the following is potentially very inefficient:

```
WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd,'02/1/2014',Date_current)  >=0) 
  AND (DATEDIFF(dd,'02/12/2014',Date_current) <=0)
```

If you have an index on `Date_Current` it will not be used because you are performing a function on it. You should instead use:

```
WHERE Date_Current >= '20140102'
AND Date_Current <= '20141202'
```

You then have a [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) query. I have had to guess at whether '02/1/2014' meant 1st February 2014, or 2nd January 2014 as it is not clear (hence the importance of my first point).

Finally (this part has already been answered but including it for completeness as I couldn't not point out the first two errors) you cannot convert to int here:

```
convert(int,'02/12/2014')
```

You presumably need to convert to date time first:

```
CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(DATETIME, '20141202'))
```

Although I suspect this is still not what you want, you are just filtering the days to those that have 41973 records or more, seems like a fairly arbitrary filter....

Answer (score 1):

You need to Cast your String Date after that only you can proceed with Int CAST

```
CAST('02/12/2014' AS Datetime)
```

Try this

```
SELECT Date_current,COUNT(*) AS 'Total' 
From Call_Register 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd,'02/1/2014',Date_current)>=0) AND   
      (DATEDIFF(dd,'02/12/2014',Date_current)<=0) 
Group By Date_current
having COUNT(*)>=(convert(int, CAST('02/12/2014' AS Datetime)) order By Date_current
```

Comment: thnx error is Solved bt Not getting expected ouput
I want output to be 
single date and total day count in front each date date

Comment: What output this gives convert(int, CAST('02/12/2014' AS Datetime)

Answer (score 1):

At last got the as for my question thnx everyone

```
   SELECT  cast(Date_current as DATE),COUNT(*) AS 'Total' 
From Call_Register 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd,'02/1/2014',Date_current)>=0) AND   
      (DATEDIFF(dd,'02/13/2014',Date_current)<=0) 
Group By  cast(Date_current as DATE)
```

can i use order by in  this cos i want it in descending order pl help for that